# Unable to remove crawl-errors from Google

Tags: google-search-console, joomla, http-code-500

When I open Google webmaster tools I have about 300+ crawl errors like these:

> http://www.verhurenhuis.nl/index.php?option=com_jea&view=properties&layout=rotterdam&Itemid=6&limitstart=220&id=255
>   500-fout    21 okt. 2011
>
> http://www.verhurenhuis.nl/index.php?option=com_jea&view=properties&layout=rotterdam&Itemid=6&limitstart=280&id=322
>   500-fout    21 okt. 2011

When I click on these links I indeed get an crawl-error. But unfortunately I don't know where to delete this errors! I am looking for it in my administration but cannot find these pages or the page who creates them.

Hope someone can help.

I am using Joomla 1.5 and the Joomla Estate Agency.

Comment: Does the error reported on that page provide a clue? ... "Layout "rotterdam" not found"

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove this error for your Google Webmaster Tools dashboard is to fix the error.

Google detected a page linked somewhere in your site is returning an error 500. The error 500 is a server error, it means something prevented your site to work properly.
Google is reporting the issue to give you the possibility to fix it.

Comment: Also, once you fix the error it may remain in that list for awhile (perhaps up to a month or longer based on my experience but they eventually seem to go away).